# ESRI fonts and QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, font

I should convert an ArcGIS cartography style (where the Esri fonts were used for the symbology) in QGIS. Is it possible to use the esri symbolic fonts and why some of them (eg ESRI Oil, Gas, & Water) are not correctly detected by other software?

Answer (score 1):

Provided they are true type fonts and provided that you don't in some way violate ESRI's licence terms by using them then you can include them in a QGIS style.

Comment: Thanks, could the problem with some fonts be due to the "&" character (eg ESRI Oil, Gas, & Water)  and could it be fixed in some way?

Answer (score -1):

You can not convert ESRI Style to be used in QGIS, because The ESRI Style are in binary encoded format, and they have not disclosed their inner structure, the only format that you can convert them directly is to **.style** format that is not supported by QGIS.

One way you can use [Arc2Earth](http://help.arc2earth.com/kb/arc2earth-desktop/export-map-symbols-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld), to convert it into SLD format, but this is not free now.

For windows, you can also use [arc2sld](https://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm) converter, to convert it to SLD. SLD generated from this does not incoporporate high level design.

One other approach that you can use, is you can create your own vector graphics, and then import them into XML, and then import them directly in QGIS, as QGIS support xml format to import symbology.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not use the correct words to explain the problem: when I say about "converting" it might be better to say "re-create" the Arcgis layers style in QGIS with its own styling tools (not a software conversion). and for this I asked for the use of the esri fonts in QGIS